# How do I use jQuery to remove the hyperlink for a certain data string value in an If/Else Statement?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write an **If/Else statement** that will display database records **WITHOUT a hyperlink**, IF it has a certain string value or word in it. What can I use in **jQuery** to **remove the hyperlink** for any database record that has the word **"street"** in the value for **"doc_location"** database category? Is it possible to remove the hyperlink displayed in the browser if the category value has http: in it?

**REST Service Database category fields and values.**

"doc_location": "http:nyc.gov/summerstreets"

"doc_name": "NY Metrics"

**Code Goal:**

**IF** the doc_location **has** the word **"street"** in it, display the value as regular text with **NO** hyperlink.

**Else** if doc_location does NOT have **"street"** in the URL then display it as usual with hyperlink.

Sigh... feel free to CORRECT me using any kind of boolean or logic operators.

```
if (item.doc_location == 'street') {
        $('#jsonData').append("<h3>Location</h3> + don't hyperlink this ???");
}
else {
        if (item.doc_location !== 'street')     
           $('#jsonData').append('<h3>Location</h3> <a href="http://www.nyc.gov">Street address</a>');
}
```

Comment: `if(/street/i.test(item.doc_location)){}` - use regex o indexof since you want to check contains

Comment: The `doc_name` you kindly shared with us... what about it? "It's there" but not a single mention about it (and it has the `Street` in it! which makes the question a bit off)

Comment: Sorry I know it looks strange but there are 20 something other records with a few that have "street" or some other word in it for the doc_location database category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to check for contains, not equals you need to use a regex or `String.indexOf()`

```
if (/street/i.test(item.doc_location)) {
    $('#jsonData').append('<h3>Location</h3>');
} else {
    $('#jsonData').append('<h3>Location</h3> <a href="http://www.nyc.gov">Street address</a>');
}
```

I used a regex here because you might need to have a case insensitive lookup.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have to wait to test your code on the server tomorrow at the office and let you know if it works.

Comment: Arun's code worked ! For any database records that have the string or word "street" in the URL, then the hyperlink was removed. And for any records without the word "street" in the URL then it remained hyperlinked as intended. The only tiny change I did was for the else statement <a href part.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var result = (!!~item.doc_location.indexOf('street')) ? '' : item.doc_location;
 $('#jsonData').append('<h3>Location</h3>' + result);
```

If you're wondering about the tilde stuff(i.e. `!!~`)... the tilde operator essentially flips the sign of and subtracts 1 from a number. so in javascript, there's "truthiness", as you know. And any number besides 0 evaluates to `true`. when we use `!!`('bang bang', or 'not not') on truthy or false-y values, they're converted into actual `Boolean`.

so, when we have a 'match', a `number >= 0` is returned from `indexOf('str')`. 
Let's say we have a match:

```
"foo".indexOf('oo'); // 1 
~"foo".indexOf('oo'); // -2
!!~"foo".indexOf('oo'); // true
```

and now we don't:

```
"foo".indexOf("your mom"); // -1
~"foo".indexOf("your mom"); // 0
!!~"foo".indexOf("your mom"); // false
```

As suggested by @RokoC.Buljan, you could also use regex to rule out case-sensitive weirdness. I went with `re.test('string')` over `'string'.match(re)` for quicker performance:

```
var location = item.doc_location,
    result = (/street/i.test(location)) 
                 ? '' 
                 : '<a href="' + location + '">Street Address</a>';
 $('#jsonData').append('<h3>Location</h3>' + result);
```

Comment: nice, just explain the `!!~` cause might not be obvious (you know, > -1 etc...)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the reminder! done. ...as best i could lol

Comment: bahaha I love it! "Your mom" LOL

Comment: If you care about bowser support and lower/uppercase matching I'd go with `item.doc_location.match(/street/i)` (or using `.test()`). Remember the browser we used to call IE?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'd say not worry about that, because URLs 99.9% of the time don't contain uppercase, but certainly can,. Rationale: I wouldn't want to send my visitors to sites written by devs that use 'cased' routes.